# How can I solve cs-cart free product promotions issue?

Tags: cs-cart

How can I solve cscart promotion free product issue.

Issue description:

When I purchase 10 products, then I get 1 product free. `<--this is working`

But when I purchase 20 products, I also get 1 product free, instead of 2 products as free `<---issue`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure that's a stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve this case is to create several pormotions.

- if there are more than 10 but lese than 20 then customer gets 1 free
  product
- if there are more than 20 but less than 30 then customer gets 2 free
  products

and so on.

The main point is that conditions in CS-Cart are universal and there is no options like scaling bonus depending on condition.

Comment: Thank you. This is not a proper solution for me because we have bulk product purchase.